# Flutter: Giving equal width to two buttons in a ButtonBar with dynamic height for long text

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

So here's my simple use case: I want to have two buttons next to each other horizontally. In native android (which is where I come from) I would have placed them in a `LinearLayout` and given them weight 1 each and setting their height to `wrap_content`.

Now, I have placed two `RaisedButton` in a `ButtonBar` widget but where I run the app I can see the second one is getting clipped. I want them to be equally spaced and have dynamic height as per their text. How can I achieve the same in flutter? Below is what I have tried so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
            title: Text("Building layouts"),
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
            )),
        body: myLayoutWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// replace this method with code in the examples below
Widget myLayoutWidget() {
  return Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ButtonBar(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("Very long text button",),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Very very very very long text button"),
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

This is how it looks right now:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried removing the ButtonBar and wrapping each RaisedButton with Expanded? This would prevent the overflow and distribute the width equally between the buttons - it would be the equivalent of a LinearLayout with 2 children with equal weight.

Comment: @Ovidiu I just tried. Wrapped the buttons in a `Row` wrapped in `Expanded` but now the second button begins right after the first with no margin and still it clips at the end since the text is very long.

Comment: @Ovidiu Oh you meant each button widget! I read it wrong. Lakhwinder Singh's answer made it click!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using  Row instead of Button Bar and add buttons to Expanded parent

```
Widget myLayoutWidget() {
  return Container(
    child: Row(

      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("Very long text button",),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Very very very very long text button"),
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```