# How to make my content responsive and not overflow on container

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is what my container looks like on the emulator (Pixel 3) :

[image]

And now this is what it looks like on my Galaxy S9 :

[image]

The text of my column is overflowing. I thought it would "adapt" automatically, but it seems that it's not the case.

The code of the 4 elements that are overflowing is :

```dart
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Row(
                                    //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.turned_in_not,
                                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                                        size: 18.0,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 7.0,),
                                      Text(
                                        'Economy',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'SamsungSans',
                                          fontSize: 15.0,
                                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.location_on,
                                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                                        size: 18.0,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 7.0,),
                                      Text(
                                        'Terminal 1',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'SamsungSans',
                                          fontSize: 15.0,
                                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),

                                ],
                              ),
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.airline_seat_legroom_normal,
                                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                                        size: 18.0,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 7.0,),
                                      Text(
                                        'Standard legroom',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          //fontFamily: 'SamsungSans',
                                          fontSize: 14.0,
                                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.card_travel,
                                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                                        size: 18.0,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 7.0,),
                                      Text(
                                        '1 included',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'SamsungSans',
                                          fontSize: 15.0,
                                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
```

Any idea on what should I change so that the text doesn't overflow its container ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57271645/2219208 check this

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to wrap your overflowing widgets with `Expanded` widget. Hope it will help.

UPD
I just used code above on some old device with mdpi resolution. To fix overflow I've added `Expanded` to the second `Column`, it solves the overflow issues, but it 'Standard legroom' text is still overflowing. So in case of really long String I would suggest to add `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` for your Text.

In case you want to keep whole string, just add `Expanded` to the overflowing `Text` widget. But in this case there will be to lines text, and it could not be a solution.

Anyway here is my final code:

```
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.turned_in_not,
                  color: Colors.grey[700],
                  size: 18.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 7.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Economy',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'SamsungSans',
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.grey[700],
                  size: 18.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 7.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Terminal 1',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'SamsungSans',
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.airline_seat_legroom_normal,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    size: 18.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 7.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      'Standard legroom',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          //fontFamily: 'SamsungSans',
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15.0,
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.card_travel,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    size: 18.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 7.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '1 included',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'SamsungSans',
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

[image: Two options[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cik1a.png)

Comment: Very well I take note ;)